# Convert a float in Pharo Smalltalk to a bytearray?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am using Pharo Smalltalk 2.0.  I need to convert a float into a ByteArray.  There seems to be no method to do this, is there a roundabout way of doing it?

For instance, `1 asFloat asByteArray` would be perfect.

Context:  I'm trying to send binary data through websocket using the Zinc Websocket package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on i386 CPU, you can do it with native boost

```
(ByteArray new: 8) nbFloat64AtOffset: 0 put: Float pi; yourself
```

Note that byte order is littleEndian in this case.

Otherwise, you have those platform independent access:

```
(ByteArray new: 8) doubleAt: 1 put: Float pi bigEndian: true ; yourself
```

Note the difference with 0-based index for first case, and 1-based for second case.

Answer (score 3):

A `Float` already is a variable class, i.e. a little bit similar to an array:

```
3.14. "=> 3.14"
3.14 size. "=> 2"
3.14 at: 1. "=> 1074339512"
3.14 at: 2. "=> 1374389535"
```

You can also modify it:

```
| f |

f := 3.14.
f at: 1 put: 10000.
f. "=> 2.1220636948306e-310"
```

With that in mind, you now can handle those two integers.

However, Pharo 2.0 typically comes with Fuel pre-installed,
and it already contains means to serialize a float:

```
ByteArray streamContents: [ :s |
  FLEncoder on: s globalEnvironment: Dictionary new do: [ :e |
    3.14 serializeOn: e ]] "=> #[64 9 30 184 81 235 133 31]"
```

Probably, you want to use the Fuel serializing altogether, if you have Pharo or
Squeak on both ends.